# Check with if and usage of section*

Tags: macros

I struggle with the syntax of the macros. Basically I want to check if I should use `\section` or the starred section `\section*` depending on the parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mySection[2]{
    \ifnum #2=1 
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\section
    \else\section*
    \fi
    {#1}
}

\begin{document}
    test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}
    
\end{document}
```

The second command receives an error `! Extra \else.` How to get the MWE working?

Comment: why do you use low-level tex instead of a test from etoolbox or expl3?

Comment: I found a working solution with the given responses - for which I'm thankful. But the given answers raise additional questions. Therefore I opened another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579233/48642. Just as a followup...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't count `\expandafter`s well. Your test file should be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mySection[2]{
    \ifnum #2=1 
    \expandafter\section
    \else\expandafter\section\expandafter*%
    \fi
    {#1}
}

\begin{document}
    test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```

The general rule: the `\expandafter`s chain must touch the `\else` in the first part of condition and the `\fi` in the second part.

Comment: Thx for the response and this works. I wasn't aware that I need to expand before the `*`.  Your general rule means that I need to have the same no of `\expandafter` in each of the branches - right?

Comment: @LeO No, you have one token in the first branch: `\section`, so you have to touch to the `\else` by one `\expandafter`. You have two tokens in the second branch: `\section` `*`. You have to touch the `\fi` by two `\expandafter`s. In general: this chain must alternate `\expandafter` `token` `\expandafter` `token` etc. `\expandafter` `token` `\fi`.

Comment: @LeO In the `\if..`-branch you need one `\expandafter`-*chain* "hitting" the token `\else`. In the `\else..`-branch you need one `\expandafter`-*chain* "hitting" the token `\fi`. The amount of `\expandafter` in the respective `\expandafter`-chain depends on how many tokens in the respective branch need to be " jumped over" for "reaching" the `\else`/the`\fi`.

Answer (score 4):

**Let's look at `\if..\else..\fi`-conditionals:**

Expanding the `\if...` of an `\if..\else..\fi` while the `\if..`-condition is fulfilled yields evaluation and removal of the tokens that are needed for finding out whether the `\if..`-condition is fulfilled.

E.g., expanding the `\ifnum` of

```
\ifnum1=1 equal\else different\fi
```

yields:  `equal \else different\fi` .

In further processing `equal` is carried out. After that `\else` is carried out/expanded.

The result of carrying out/expanding `\else` is removing the subsequent tokens including the matching `\fi`.

The previous sentence rephrased in other words:
Expanding the `\else` of an `\if..\else..\fi` while the `\if..`-condition is fulfilled yields removal of the tokens that form the "false"-branch and removal of the matching `\fi`.

E.g., *(click the image to enlarge)*

[image]

yields:  *(click the image to enlarge)*

[image]

yields:  *(click the image to enlarge)*

[image]

Expanding the `\if..` of an `\if..\else..\fi` while the `\if..`-condition is not fulfilled yields evaluation and removal of the tokens that are needed for finding out whether the `\if..`-condition is fulfilled and removal of all tokens that form the "true"-branch, including the `\else`-token that marks the end of the "true"-branch.

(Expansion of the `\else` of an `\if..\else..\fi` while the `\if..`-condition is not fulfilled does not occur: As just said: In this case the token `\else` is removed as the marker of the end of the "true"-branch. As it is removed it cannot be expanded.)

E.g., expanding the `\ifnum` of

```
\ifnum1=2 equal\else different\fi
```

yields: `different\fi`.

`different` is carried out. After that `\fi` is carried out=expanded=removed.

Be aware that the term "evaluation" in the phrase "evaluation and removal of the tokens that are needed for finding out whether the `\if..`-condition is fulfilled" with some `\if..`-conditionals subsumes expansion of expandable tokens—this is the case, e.g., with `\if` and `\ifcat`—and with some `\if..`-conditionals does not subsume  expansion of expandable tokens—this is the case, e.g., with `\ifx`. With some `\if..`-conditionals—e.g., `\ifhmode`, `\ifvmode`, `\ifmmode`, `\ifinner`— no tokens at all are needed for finding out whether the `\if..`-condition is fulfilled.

---

**Let's look at your definition of `\mySection`:**

> ```
> \newcommand\mySection[2]{
>     \ifnum #2=1 
>     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\section
>     \else\section*
>     \fi
>     {#1}
> }
> ```

With your code in case of `#2` being `0` the tokens forming the "true"-branch of `\mySection`'s `\ifnum..\else..\fi` are discarded whereby the token `\else`  denotes the end of the "true"-branch and is discarded, too. The tokens behind the `\else` forming the "false"-branch are not discarded but are carried out. The token `\fi` belonging to `\mySection`'s `\ifnum..\else..\fi` is not removed from the input-stack before carrying out `\section*`. Therefore the argument of `\section*`  will be the token `\fi`, not the sequence `{#1}`.  Expanding the `\section`-macro/expanding macros underlying the `\section`-macro means replacing the control-sequence-token in question by its definition-text while inserting the arguments for the parameters. Hereby the `\fi` coming as `\section*`'s argument erroneously matches up some `\if..`-`⟨some parameter #1/#2/whatever⟩`-`\else`-`\fi`-expression coming from the definition-text of some macro underlying the `\section`-command. Thus the `\else` behind `⟨some parameter #1/#2/whatever⟩` is considered an extra `\else`.
(The `\fi` behind what is considered an extra `\else` is not considered an extra `\fi` but "helps" matching things up instead of the `\fi` belonging to `\mySection`'s `\ifnum..\else..\fi` which is consumed as `\section*`'s argument.)

With your code in case of `#2` being `1` the first `\expandafter`-chain (consisting of the 1st and the 3rd `\expandafter`) "hits" the `\else`. Therefore `\else` gets expanded (and hereby removed) which yields the discarding of the entire "false"-branch including the `\fi` which marks the end of the "false"-branch. The second `\expandafter`-chain (consisting of the second `\expandafter`) then "hits" the `{` of `{#1}` which has no effect as `{` is not expandable.

---

In case `#2=1` have TeX remove the `*` of the sequence `\section*` via `\@firstoftwo`:

```
\documentclass{aricle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mySection[2]{%
  \ifnum#2=1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi\section*{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```

If you don't like `\expandafter` you can `\exchange`  `\@firstoftwo` and `\fi`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\mySection[2]{%
  \ifnum #2=1 \exchange\@firstoftwo\fi\section*{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It gives me an idea how to approach my scenario. While it seems to work it fails in my given scenario. I raised another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579233/48642. Perhaps you can point out why your proposed solution fails. Would be out of curiosity.

Comment: Although I figured out that you use your sample just for demonstration I didn't succeed to apply it correctly (following the standard solution proposed by egreg)

Answer (score 3):

A standard way to do this job is

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mySection[2]{%
  \ifnum #2=1
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\section}{\section*}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```

so the conditional is completely removed before choosing the desired path.

There are many other ways, even some that require no `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\mySection[2]{%
  \ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{1}{\section}{\section*}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```

Without packages (but a fairly recent LaTeX kernel)

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mySection{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF {#2=1}{\section}{\section*}{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

test
\mySection{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```

The last one can be extended to support the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mySection{O{#2}mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF {#3=1}{\section[#1]}{\section*}{#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mySection[short title for toc]{title}{1}
\mySection{title}{0}

\end{document}
```