# Macro check for boolean key

Tags: macros

My main focus is to extend the already given sample for [more sectionings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31010/48642) by additional features (e.g. subtitle). While I succeed with the subtitle I struggled with the [macro query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578995/48642) about the `\expandafter`. Thanks to the provided samples I figured out how a working sample could look like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}


\makeatletter
\define@key{mosquito}{hideInToC}[false]{\def\mosquito@hideInToC{#1}}
\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
    \setkeys{mosquito}{hideInToC={},#1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax\expandafter\chapter\or
    %section
    \ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\section%
    \else\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\section\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter*%
    \fi
    \else\expandafter\subsection%
    \fi
    {#3}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

++++++++++ after ToC********

    \sectionLvl{1}{title}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC]{1}{title1}
    \sectionLvl{1}{title2}
    \sectionLvl{2}{title2-1}
\end{document}
```

Which works in general but leaves some questions open from the previous answers. My two questions are:

1. According the `keyval` docu I can define a boolean value. But the docu lacks of a sample how to check the value.  `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty` is working - but is it the best way to check a boolean value?
2. In the given answers for the [macro query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578995/48642) I found solutions like `\ifnum#2=1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi\section*{#1}%` which look great. But when I try to apply it here with `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi\section*%` the evalutation fails always.

So in total I have a working solution. But I'm curious about the details why it fails and  why the proposed approaches fail in the given scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ad question 1:**

I think the classic way of handling the boolean would be using boolean keys as provided by packages like [xkeyval](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) or [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) or by [expl3](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3).

If you don't like to use such packages/interfaces, you can define your own mechanism for cranking out by means of delimited arguments whether the value "true/yes" or the value "false/no" or something else is provided and setting an `\if⟨name of if⁠-⁠switch⟩`-switch accordingly by applying one of the commands `\⁠⟨name of if⁠-⁠switch⟩true`/`\⁠⟨name of if⁠-⁠switch⟩false`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% \truefalsefork{<value>}%
%               {<tokens if <value>=true/yes>}%
%               {<tokens if <value>=false/no>}%
%               {<tokens> if <value> neither is true/yes nor is false/no}
%
\@ifdefinable\gobbletorelax{\long\def\gobbletorelax#1\relax{}}%
\newcommand\truefalsefork[1]{%
  \lowercase{\@truefalsefork{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\@truefalsefork[4]{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletorelax#1\relax}$%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \selecttruefalsecase
    \relax#1\relax yes\relax false\relax no\relax{#2}%
    \relax true\relax#1\relax false\relax no\relax{#2}%
    \relax true\relax yes\relax #1\relax no\relax{#3}%
    \relax true\relax yes\relax false\relax#1\relax{#3}%
    \relax true\relax yes\relax false\relax no\relax{#4}\relax\relax\relax\relax
  }{#4}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\selecttruefalsecase{%
  \long\def\selecttruefalsecase#1\relax true\relax yes\relax false\relax no\relax#2#3\relax\relax\relax\relax{#2}%
}%
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Infrastructure for boolean-key hideInToc
%
\newcommand\hideInTocErrordefault[1]{%
   \PackageError{sectionLvl}{%
      Macro \string\sectionLvl:\MessageBreak 
      Invalid value '\detokenize{#1}'\MessageBreak
      for key hideInToC\on@line.\MessageBreak
      Value "true" is assumed%
   }{%
      Only values true/false/yes/no are allowed!\MessageBreak 
      (Lettercasing doesn't matter.)\MessageBreak
      Value "true" is assumed.%
   }%
   \hideInToctrue
}%
\newif\ifhideInToc
\define@key{mosquito}{hideInToC}[true]{%
  \truefalsefork{#1}{\hideInToctrue}{\hideInTocfalse}{\hideInTocErrordefault{#1}}%
}%
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
    \setkeys{mosquito}{hideInToC=false, #1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax
      \expandafter\chapter
    \or
      %section
      \ifhideInToc\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {\expandafter\section\expandafter*}{\expandafter\section}%
    \else
      \expandafter\subsection
    \fi
    {#3}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

%++++++++++ after ToC********

    \sectionLvl{1}{title}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC=TrUe]{1}{title1}
    % Check the error-message-mechanism by uncommenting the next line:
    % \sectionLvl[hideInToC=WeiRd]{1}{title1}
    \sectionLvl{1}{title2}
    \sectionLvl{2}{title2-1}

\end{document}
```

Be aware that this is sort of a poor-man's implementation of a boolean-key.

The packages mentioned above provide more sophisticated routines.

**Ad question 2:**

When looking at the code presented by you, I see the following:

As the `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty..\else..\fi`-thingie is nested within the last `\or`-branch of an `\ifcase..\or..\else..\fi`-thingie,  both within the "true"-branch and within the "false"-branch of  the `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty..\else..\fi`-thingie  you have taken measures for ensuring that an `\expandafter`-chain is present which triggers expansion of the subsequent `\else` of the surrounding `\ifcase..\or..\else..\fi`-thingie which in turn leads to the removal of the entire "surrounding" "else"-branch and the `\fi` before `\section`/`\section*` gets carried out. Thus due to these `\expandafter`-chains both `\section` from the `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty..\else..\fi`-thingie's "false"-branch and `\section*` from the `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty..\else..\fi`-thingie's "true"-branch can fetch `{#3}` as its argument as no other tokens stemming from the surrounding `\ifcase..`-expression are in the way.

If you just replace the `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty..\else..\fi`-thingie by something like the sequence `\ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi\section*`, then such an `\expandafter`-chain is not there. Thus the tokens `\else..\fi` from the surrounding `\ifcase..\or..\else..\fi`-thingie are still there when the argument of `\section`/`\section*` is gathered. Thus not the sequence `{#3}` but the token `\else` will be the argument of `\section`/`\section*`, leading to unexpected results/unexpected behavior.

You could define an additional macro `\@twooftwo` and do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}


\makeatletter
\define@key{mosquito}{hideInToC}[false]{\def\mosquito@hideInToC{#1}}
\newcommand\@twooftwo[2]{#1#2}
\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
    \setkeys{mosquito}{hideInToC={},#1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax
      \expandafter\chapter
    \or
      %section
      \ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@twooftwo\fi
      {\expandafter\section}{\expandafter*}%
    \else
      \expandafter\subsection
    \fi
    {#3}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

++++++++++ after ToC********

    \sectionLvl{1}{title}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC]{1}{title1}
    \sectionLvl{1}{title2}
    \sectionLvl{2}{title2-1}
\end{document}
```

You could also do the "standard" `\if..\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi`-thingie:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}


\makeatletter
\define@key{mosquito}{hideInToC}[false]{\def\mosquito@hideInToC{#1}}
\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
    \setkeys{mosquito}{hideInToC={},#1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax
      \expandafter\chapter
    \or
      %section
      \ifx\mosquito@hideInToC\@empty\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
      {\expandafter\section}{\expandafter\section\expandafter*}%
    \else
      \expandafter\subsection
    \fi
    {#3}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

++++++++++ after ToC********

    \sectionLvl{1}{title}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC]{1}{title1}
    \sectionLvl{1}{title2}
    \sectionLvl{2}{title2-1}
\end{document}
```

But these are just examples exhibiting how to get the `\expandafter`-tokens in line for removing the `\ifcase..\or..\else..\fi`-thingie's `\else..\fi` before carrying out `\section`/`\section*` and hereby having TeX gather `\section`/`\section*`'s argument.

I don't recommend this because you don't have infrastructure for handling the situation of the user providing an inappropriate value for the key `hideInToC`.

Comment: Thx a lot for your elaborated response. I highly appreciate to get an idea what's going on behind the curtain. I get a better understanding about checks and how conditional branches are expanded. As well as how TeX handles tokens. Just a quick remark to your sample: The very last sample is compiling while your alternative isn't. But this doesn't harm much since I guess its just for sketching a possible alternative.

Comment: @LeO The alternative is compiling now, too: I made the mistake  ;-(  of defining `\newcommand\twooftwo...` and using `\@twooftwo`.  (The `@` was missing in one place.) Thus `\@twooftwo` was undefined.  Now it is `\newcommand\@twooftwo...`. ;-)   I appreciate questions which provide opportunity to explain how things get processed by TeX and thus to provide pieces of a "mosaic", the totality of which, over time, provides an overview of how the different stages of processing .tex-input work and intertwine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple boolean option can be defined by package `kvoptions`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=mosquito,
  prefix=mosquito@,
}
\DeclareBoolOption{hideInToC}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{mosquito}{#1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax  % 0 = chapter
      \def\tmp@mosquito{\chapter}%
    \or  % 1 = section
      \ifmosquito@hideInToC
        \def\tmp@mosquito{\section*}%
      \else
        \def\tmp@mosquito{\section}%
      \fi
    \else  % subsection
      \def\tmp@mosquito{\subsection}%
    \fi
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \tmp@mosquito{#3}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \bigskip
    \hrule

    \sectionLvl{1}{Title 1 (shown)}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC]{1}{Title 2 (hideInToC)}
    \sectionLvl{1}{Title 3 (shown)}
    \sectionLvl{2}{SubTitle 4 (shown)}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Remarks:**

- The `\expandafter` chains are replaced by a simple temporary macro `\tmp@mosquito` definition to ease readability and maintenance of the code. We do not need expandability here, because neither `\chapter` nor `\section` are fully expandable.
- It is not fully clear, whether key `hideInToC` should act globally or locally. The usage implies local scope. Therefore, I have put the key setting inside a group, thus that `hideInToC` applies to the current `\sectionLvl` only.

**Ad 1:**

With package `keyval` and without package `kvoptions`, a boolean option definition consists of three parts:

1. Definition of a boolean switch:

   ```
    \newif\ifmosquito@hideInToC
   ```
2. Optional. The default is `false` as usually expected. It can be changed to `true`:

   ```
    \mosquito@hideInToCtrue
   ```
3. Option definition:

   ```
    \define@key{mosquito}{hideInToC}[true]{%
      \csname mosquito@hideInToC#1\endcsname
    }
   ```

   The only allowed values are `true` and `false`. Other values are ignored, because
   `\csname...\endcsname` behaves as `\relax` if the command sequence is not defined.

   It is possible to add an error check:

   ```
    \define@key{mosquito}{hideInToC}[true]{%
      \ifcsname mosquito@hideInToC#1\endcsname
        \csname mosquito@hideInToC#1\endcsname
      \else
        % Error message (\PackageError, \latex@error, ...)
      \fi
    }
   ```

Usage forms:

```
    hideInToC       % true
    hideInToC=true  % true
    hideInToC=false % false
```

It is possible to define an opposite boolean option:

```
    \define@key{mosquito}{showInToC}[true]{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname if#1\endcsname\iftrue
        \mosquito@hideInToCfalse
      \else
        % Caution: \iffalse inside \if constructs needs to be protected
        \expandafter\ifx\csname if#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname iffalse\endcsname
          \mosquito@hideInToCtrue
        \else
          % Error message
        \fi
      \fi
    }
```

Then:
showInToC        % hideInToC=false
showInToC=true   % hideInToC=false
showInToC=false  % hideInToC=true

It is a one-liner with package `kvoptions`:

```
\DeclareComplementaryOption{showInToC}{hideInToC}
```

Comment: I'm highly appreciate your explanation in detail. Thx very much. I think go for the `kvoptions` although this seems another mystery. As far as I understood I can declare a `boolean` and than easily query it by `\def\tmp@mosquito`. If I want to have a `subtile` I need to use `\DeclareStringOption{subtitle}` and I guess with `\setkeys` the value is set as well. But how to access it from within `\sectionLvl`?

Comment: Another comment: If I stick to the `keyval` option than I would use `\ifmosquito@hideInToC` but this somehow fails. Perhaps I use it in the wrong way. Anyway - I won't use both options. Thx for clarifying different options.

Comment: @LeO The boolean option is unrelated to `\def\tmp@mosquito`. The boolean option is processed and the result (`\chapter`, `\section`, ...) is stored in the temporary macro `\tmp@mosquito`, to avoid lots of `\expandafter`.

Comment: @LeO `\DeclareStringOption{subtitle}` with the `\SetupKeyvalOptions` as in the example saves the option setting in macro `\mosquito@subtitle`.

Comment: @LeO Maybe you have forgotten `\newif\ifmosquito@hideInToC` if you define the boolean option without package `kvoptions`.

Comment: I think declared the `\DeclareStringOption` properly. Accessing them via `\mosquito@subtitle` won't help. Is it useful to open a new q? Or better to share a link in Overleaf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118594/discussion-between-leo-and-heiko-oberdiek).

Comment: @LeO Yes, make a new question with an example. I am no longer a frequent visitor of the site.

Comment: I added the sample in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579390/48642