# Usage of string value in kvoptions

Tags: kvoptions

I followed [the sample](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579323/48642) of Heiko with very excellent explanation about his approach of my request. Since my main idea is to have as well a subtitle I'm little bit stuck why the ˋsubtitleˋ is not set - or better said: I have no idea how to access it properly for a printout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=mosquito,
    prefix=mosquito@,
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBoolOption{hideInToC}
\DeclareStringOption{subtitle}

\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
    \begingroup
    \setkeys{mosquito}{#1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax  % 0 = chapter
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\chapter}%
    \or  % 1 = section
    \ifmosquito@hideInToC
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\section*}%
    \else
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\section}%
    \fi
    \else  % subsection
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\subsection}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \tmp@mosquito{#3}{
        {sub: \mosquito@subtitle}
}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \bigskip
    \hrule
    
    \sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle}]{1}{Title 1 (shown)}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC]{1}{Title 2 (hideInToC)}
    \sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle2}]{1}{Title 3 (shown)}
    \sectionLvl{2}{SubTitle 4 (shown)}
\end{document}
```

Since I switch from ˋkeyvalˋ to ˋkvoptionsˋ I wonder what are the major differences. I'm aware that the syntax is different but has the one or other benefits in sense of performance (when using via LuaHBTex) or better robustness?

Comment: why do you require from your user to use an additional argument, to remember what the number in argument 2 means, and unusual boolean handling? I would setup an interface like `\sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle},level=chapter,toc=false,number=false]{Title 1 (shown)}`.

Comment: Well ... yeah ... might be an option to think of. Its more that it evolves in a certain direction... I took it from other samples - copy'n paste and now a certain complexitey is reached... I would take the `level` still as numeric but I appreciate the idea for the `toc` although I think `number` is not really required.

Comment: Just an additional note: some of the parameters are optional and one mandatory. Therefore I don't know if it's useful to change the whole interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\setkeys` is invoked inside a group to keep the settings local. `\tmp@mosquito` is expanded by `\expandafter\endgroup\tmp@mosquito` right before ending the group.
`\mosquito@subtitle`, however, is reset by `\endgroup` to the empty string.
Thus, you need a more sophisticated version. The following code keeps `\chapter`, `\section` outside the group, but expands `\tmp@mosquito` and `\mosquito@subtitle` before ending the group. The unknown tokens of the title in `#3` are protected from the hard expansion of `\edef`  by `\unexpanded`. It was not clear to me, where the subtitle should go, after the chapter/section title or inside. The example uses the more difficult inside version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=mosquito,
    prefix=mosquito@,
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBoolOption{hideInToC}
\DeclareStringOption{subtitle}

\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
    \begingroup
    \setkeys{mosquito}{#1}%
    \ifcase#2\relax  % 0 = chapter
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\chapter}%
    \or  % 1 = section
    \ifmosquito@hideInToC
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\section*}%
    \else
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\section}%
    \fi
    \else  % subsection
    \def\tmp@mosquito{\subsection}%
    \fi
    \edef\x{%
      \endgroup
      \expandafter\noexpand\tmp@mosquito{%
        \unexpanded{#3}%
        \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty
        \else
          \space(sub: \unexpanded\expandafter{\mosquito@subtitle})%
        \fi
      }%
    }%
    \x
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \bigskip
    \hrule

    \sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle}]{1}{Title 1 (shown)}
    \sectionLvl[hideInToC]{1}{Title 2 (hideInToC)}
    \sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle2}]{1}{Title 3 (shown)}
    \sectionLvl{2}{SubTitle 4 (shown)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx for the response and thanx for the clarification.